# How to use virtual connection between matlab simulik and arduino in isis proteus?

Tags: matlab

I don't know how to connect between matlab simulik and arduino card in isis proteus by using a virtual ports

Comment: have you looked at any of the tutorials on the internet?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't find answer to this question by tutorial

Comment: were you able to create a virtual port in proteus?

Comment: I don't know how to create it

Comment: then, you are asking the wrong question and you are searching for the wrong tutorial on the web ............ find a tutorial about creating a virtual port in proteus  ..... find one about creating a virtual port in matlab also ...... i think that you only have to do one for your purpose